# How to make slider like this in wordpress?

Tags: plugins

https://agilisium.com/

How he made home page slider as well as tabs in slider ?

Can anyone help me with that?

Its made with Wordpress and I also want same to be done.

Answer (score 0):

If you go to www.builtwith.com you can see what any given developer used to create a website. In this case the CMS is a simple Wordpress site using the layer slider plugin for this slider and styling in Bakery Builder (drag and drop builder software like Elementor), which is a responsive slider plugin + CSS styling and that's about it. With a bit of CSS knowledge you should be able to emulate this slider pretty easily. I would guess though it's a premium template he or she used and they just set it and forgot it. Pretty simple!

Answer (score 0):

You can check which plugin they are using by this link - https://www.wpthemedetector.com.
They are using plugin- https://codecanyon.net/item/kreatura-slider-plugin-for-wordpress/1362246?irgwc=1 you can create the same by following the plugin documentation.